git clone only clone folder
i create a file hello.txt in hello folder inside repocentral folder with command-line.
The commnand-line i use to create them:
git init repocentral
cd repocentral
mkdir hello
cd hello
echo "hello everyone" > hello.txt

But when i use this command-line, it only have folder dev1 without everything inside
git clone repocentral dev1

i ever try use ls in dev1 folder but it hollow !!
i want ask reason why my git clone are not working and how to fix it!

Did you git add and git commit anything?

git clone is working. You never committed anything to repocentral, the repository is empty, so you cloned an empty repository. git clone clones the committed changes, not the files sitting in the directory.
You might be used to other software which auto-saves for you. Version control is different. Git does not automatically track files in the repository directory, nor does it automatically record changes. You must tell it exactly which files to track and what changes to commit to the repository with git add and git commit. Having to consider what is committed, and recording why the change was made, is important for version control.
Read 2.2 Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository to learn more.

To add all the files that you have edited, then commit and push them to the remote repository:
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "My first commit message"
$ git push


You first need to add the contents of the folder to the git repository.
Here is the commands you entered, followed by the two commands you need to enter afterwards for the files to be included in the git repository.
git init repocentral
cd repocentral
mkdir hello
cd hello
echo "hello everyone" > hello.txt
cd ..
git add *
git commit -m "Added some files!"

